# Como fazer notificações igual as do Facebook? AngularJS ou JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, ionic, http

Gostaria de incluir notificações no meu app. O app será em Ionic, AngularJS, jQuery, NodeJS... existe uma forma de o app rodar uma função a cada X tempo? Essa função daria um get no NodeJS...

Comment: Sua pergunta é bastante genérica a meu ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para notificação no Ionic utilizo o OneSignal (https://onesignal.com/).

E caso queira disparar as notificações pela api em nodejs utilizo onesignal-node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-node), esta é a mais completa.

Você também pode utilizar o próprio site do OneSignal para disparar as notificações para app, selecionar para quais usuários, por tags, por grupos entre outros.